# azure devops pipeline loop task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have this variable

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=others_sql_server;]$others_sql_server"
```

Its value is for example "`aaa|bbb|ccc`". I would like to use it for looping a task

```
- ${{ each dbi in split(variables.others_sql_server, '|') }}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "XXXXX"
      inputs:
```

This does not work. Any solution?

Riccardo

Answer (score 3):

Nope, for-each loops can only be applied on parameters, not on outputs/variables from previous jobs since those could not be compiled at time of pipeline start.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword

You'll probably need to create a custom script and do a loop in there and apply your logic.